# How to receive continuous incoming data from a serial port (MCU) in vb

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I am working on a project to receive and send data to a micro controller using a Visual Basic application. I am using Visual Studio 2008. I have done coding to send data on button click event.

But I am stuck at how to receive incoming data to serial port continually from MCU and store it to an integer or string type data in VB.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://www.codeworks.it/net/VBNetRs232.htm). Wrap a loop around the read operation. Use a low timeout and ignore timeout exceptions.